# How are CopyToOutputDirectory conflicts for identically-named files resolved in a dotnet build?

Tags: c#, .net, build

I have 4 projects, with dependencies (as part of a wider set of dependencies):

```
  X --- A --- B
  |
  |---- Z
```

Projects `B` and `Z` both contain a file named `conflict.txt`. Both are marked as `Content` and `Copy if Newer`.

This dependency chain is part of a wider set of dependencies, and some other projects *do* require the `conflict.txt` from B.

How does a `dotnet build` determine which file to put into the output directory for `X`?

Can I constrain it in any way -- ideally to ensure that I only take the file from `Z` for `X`?

Comment: Just mark the one you don't want as "Do not copy"?

Comment: That's a good start. I'll edit: this is embedded in a larger solution, some projects of which do need the file from B